# How do you run a file-reading program on itself in C?

Tags: c

I have only Java experience, and I'm starting to learn C through the K&R C book, second addition. In the first chapter, one of their examples is this program which simply counts the white space, characters, and digits:

```
#include <stdio.h>


main()
{
int c, i, nwhite, nother;
int ndigit[10];

nwhite = nother = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    ndigit[i] = 0;
}

while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
        ++ndigit[c-'0'];
    }
    else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'){
        ++nwhite;
    }
    else{
        ++nother;
    }
}

printf("digits =");
for(i = 0; i <10; ++i){
    printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
}
printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
```

}

Next, in the book they say "the output of this program run on itself is " followed by its output. However, I've compiled the program in the terminal and just cannot figure out how to run this program on itself in C. In java, I would have passed the file name to String args[0] and read it from there, but this program doesn't have any similar mechanism, and doesn't seem to have an args array to pass to. Even if it did, the code itself doesn't seem to read from any particular file (for example, in java you could specifically set up a scanner to read args[0], and then call scanner.next() etcetc, but in this program, it just calls getchar() on seemingly nothing). Can anyone help me clear this up so I can run the program before continuing? Sorry if this is something super simple, like I said my experience in C is nonexistent. Thank you!

Also my formatting on this website is trash I apologize

Comment: I've created the program above called t.c and compiled it.  I run it like this : $ cat t.c | ./a.out  <RETURN>                                                                                         
digits = 9 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1, white space = 146, other = 324   or, you can run it like this :  ./a.out < t.c <RETURN>                                                                                              
digits = 9 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1, white space = 146, other = 324

Comment: K&R is outdated since 18 years and does not cover modern standard C. Get a more recent book, which covers **at least** C99, better the current version C11.

Answer (score 4):

I assume they intend to run this program like so:

```
./example < example.c
```

You are correct about the fact that the program does not open a file and it does not use arguments. The getchar() function operates on stdin.
The program does not make much sense if you use it on the compiled file, so that is why I assumed it is supposed to be run with the source file. I see how the instructions are confusing.